# Error when restarting newly installed Apache2 Server (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux, apache2

I recently installed Apache2, which worked fine and I could restart it and everything.
I then installed MySQL - With 0 Errors.

When I installed phpmyadmin, I was told to add the following

```
> Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Just below this

```
#Include the virtual host configurations:
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

But it seems to somehow have broken my script and im not quite sure on how to fix it

```
> 
> Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Invalid command
> '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
> module not included in the server configuration Action 'configtest'
> failed. The Apache error log may have more information.    ...fail!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You omitted the `Include` directive.

```
#Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```